# Conditional routing in react v5.2

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I have my router setup like below :

```
  return (
    <Router history={history}>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={SearchPage} />
        <Route path="/search" component={SearchPage} />
        <Route path="/searchResults" component={SearchResultsPage} />
        <Route path="/SearchResultsDetails" component={SearchResultsDetailsPage} />
        <Route path="/eventDetails/:ID/:Type" component={EventDetailsPage} />
        <Route path="/approver" component={ApproverPage} />
        <Route component={PageNotFound} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
```

Now I need restrict users routing based on hasAccess Variables which are passed as props.

Which i have impleted like below :

```
   return (
    <Router history={history}>
      <Switch>

        { !isAuthenticated ?
          <Route component={UnAuthorizedAccess} /> : null
        }

        { hasSearchAccess ?
          <>
            <Route exact path="/" component={SearchPage} />
            <Route path="/search" component={SearchPage} />
            <Route path="/searchResults" component={SearchResultsPage} />
            <Route path="/SearchResultsDetails" component={SearchResultsDetailsPage} />
          </> : <Route component={UnAuthorizedAccess} />
        }

{ hasEventAccess ? 

<Route path="/eventDetails/:ID/:Type" component={EventDetailsPage} /> : 
<Route component={UnAuthorizedAccess}}

}

        { hasApproverAccess ? 
          <Route path="/approver" component={ApproverPage} /> : <Route component={UnAuthorizedAccess}
         }

        <Route component={PageNotFound} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
```

Problem :  When i search for /someRandomPageNotFound, it doesnt take me to pageNotFound , instead it shows an blank page. Same for the hasEventAccess and hasApproverAccess, it shows a blank screen ..

I am expecting it to evaluate the other conditions and render appropriate page but looks like it doesn't. How can this be solved.

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved the functionality by - Checking the requested route , and then checking if the user has access to the route  :

```
<Route path="/search">
          {hasSearchAccess?
            <Route component={SearchPage} />
            : null}
        </Route>

 <Route path="/approve">
          {hasApproverAccess ?
            <Route path="/approve" component={ApproverPage} /> :
            null}
        </Route>
 <Route path="/*">
      {
          !hasSearchAccess||
          !hasApproverAccess ?
         <Route component={UnAuthorizedAccess} /> : 
         <Route component={PageNotFound} />
      }
    </Route>
```